# Can't put permitAll() in behind the loginpage()

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I got an error when I put `permitAll()` in behind the `loginpage()`, here is my `configure()`:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
}
```

This is my console log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.shopme.admin.ShopmeBackEndApplication.main(ShopmeBackEndApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport.permitAll(PermitAllSupport.java:51) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport.permitAll(PermitAllSupport.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.updateAccessDefaults(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java:392) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.init(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java:232) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer.init(FormLoginConfigurer.java:231) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer.init(FormLoginConfigurer.java:71) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:285) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:83) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:305) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

When I remove `permitAll()`, no error in the console, but I can't log in to it, there is no 403 forbidden error code when I remove `permitAll()`:

> This page isn't working
> Localhost redirected you too many times.
> Try clearing your cookies.
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
> Reload

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmYcv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trusting this clear error message:

> permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()

, we should *use* `http.authorizeRequests()` (without `Http` (in between..this has different api);)!

---

..or not use `permitAll`.

---

Javadocs (with examples!):

- [`authorizeRequests()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests())
- [`authorizeHttpRequests()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests())

Comment: Just to add that this is gonna be fixed in `5.7.0`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/10543